# Unhandled exceptions in tasks and azure worker roles

Tags: c#, azure

I have a Azure worker role and I run multiple tasks in that.

Any unhandled exception in any of the tasks can cause role to recycle?

For example in the event viewer I saw the following stacktrace and I believe it caused role to recycle.

> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__1(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Answer (score 2):

Anything that causes the Run() method to return on the WorkerRole, it will caused the role to recycle. That obviously includes unhandled exceptions.